# How can I find the trashed or deleted posts in a WordPress database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a migration, been given a wordpress site, and I'm intended to migrate it to a new one, maded by me. I need to do a script to get all the useful posts (whitout the draft, the trashed or deleted ones and so on). But I don't know the data base logic to tag the diferents type of posts.

Comment: Is it on active installation? I mean you are limited to Mysql or you still can execute queries on the old installation?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with "execute queries on the old inst". Yes, it is active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well on the old installation, you still can clean your database and keep only published post using a Plugin like **Trash emptier**

Otherwise Warning !!! This must be done After a DB Backup !!! 
On MySql you can execute these queries:

STEP 1: Check query results using SELECT:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON ( a.ID = b.post_id )
WHERE post_status = 'trash';
```

STEP 2 : Delete when sure about the targeted posts :

```
delete a,b
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON ( a.ID = b.post_id )
WHERE post_status = 'trash';
```

There are other post_status you can check on your database and that you would like to purge too. like **auto-draft** or **draft** ...

Comment: I see that there's a lot posts with the status "inherit", whats that? I couldn't find any status reference yet. I mean, a list where there's all of them..

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-status/#inherit Like mentioned here, Inherit staus refers to parent' post. It means they follow their parents status... You don't delete them unless you are sure their parents are irrelevant. Another query where you join based on their parent status ;)

Comment: Some plugins like this one would spare you headaches and the complexity of posts relationships  : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clean-up-optimizer/